# Removing a WordPress filter by calling a PHP function with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to remove the filter by calling a PHP function using and it's not working.

Here is my code

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function in_right_place()
{
    var x="<?php in_right_place(); ?>";
    alert(x);
    return false;
}
window.onload = in_right_place;
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
function in_right_place()
{
remove_action( 'login_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );
}
?>
```

This doesn't work, probably for good reasons for professional eyes,
but I don't know what to do next to make it work

This is a first step, at the end I want to Call this function on a specific condition, But can't make the first step work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to make ajax request to wordpress. something like this in `functions.php` or in a custom plugin (php file you are referring to)

```
function in_right_place()
{
    remove_action( 'login_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );
    die('done');
}
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_in_right_place", "in_right_place");
add_action("wp_ajax_in_right_place", "in_right_place");
```

In your `js` do something like this (assuming you have jQuery if not see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery))

```
jQuery.post(
"http://yoursite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php ", 
{
    'action': 'in_right_place'
}, 
function(response){
    alert('The server responded: ' + response);
});
```

more details [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) and [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've taken a look at the more detail page but I didn't understand how to call the function using Ajax. I think it's above my coding level. 

Do you know how to do the Ajax side properly?

Comment: That's awesome, I think it's beginning to work. now It shows the message, but the filter wasn't removed, (I've checked in the header)

Any idea why?

Comment: @user3234831 there should be a better way for what you are trying to do. header is written when page is rendered so you need to create a logic there. does header persist if you reload the page ?

Comment: Yes even after I refresh the page I get the message, it says (The server responded: done),,, but the header is still X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN.  Maybe there is another way to do it I wouldn't know where to start that's the best one I've found, and the one that worked when I just placed the remove_action in functions.php

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, It seems that what I wanted to achieve is impossible since the PHP section was already executed before the JavaScript. But what you've written above does work for passing messages so I thank you again.